# Accessing List members in ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a `list` in `ViewData`. How can I access a specific member, for examples the first item?

I want to specify the default value of a `dropdownlist`.

This is my current Template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["units"])
)
```

And what I'm looking for is something like: `ViewData["units"][0].Id`

Comment: If the value of the property you are binding to matches one of the option values, then that item will be selected, so set the value of the property in the controller before you pass the model to the view

Comment: I can't do that. They're inside a Grid and this its editor template. Actually, my problem is that the first Item never has a value. So I should select something else than first one. But I'm sure it has an ID.

Comment: I assume you did not understand my comment. If your options have values (say 1 - 10) and the value of `m` is 3, then the 3rd option will be selected

Comment: When I load the page, the first value of checkbox is selected, but if I post the page that way, I don't get a value. I have to select the first Item manually. Any idea?