# How can I set default value for a foreign key colum in Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the Kendo Grid there is a foreign key column, and I retrieve the select list from `ViewData`. Grid's edit mode is `InLine`.

When I want to add a new record, the first item is selected. If I don't change it and don't select anything else, column's value will be `null` on the server side.

How can I specify a default value for this column? Please note that `ID`'s are user-generated and I'm not able to guess which Id will the first Item.

This is the Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<InvtMat>()
    .Name("BOM")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.ForeignKey(x => x.CGoodCode, (IEnumerable)ViewData["Goods"], "Id", "Text");
        // removed for brevity
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
    })
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(ds => 
        ds.Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(x => x.CGoodCode);
            model.Id(x => x.CGoodCode1);
        })
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default value for Grid's model inside `DataSource.Model` section.

Here is an example:

```
.DataSource(ds => 
    ds.Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
            model.Id(x => x.CGoodCode);
            model.Field(x => x.CGoodCode).DefaultValue(0);
    })
)
```

Because you don't know what default value you must write there, then you should find it first before you define the Grid. I suppose you have something like this in your controller:

```
var goods = // get goods from DB.
var goodsDV= goods.First().Id;

ViewData["Goods"] = goods;
ViewData["GoodsDefaultValue"] = goodsDV;
```

Or you could also perform this in razor view

```
@{
    var firstGood = ((IEnumerable<Good>)ViewData["Goods"]).First();
    ViewData["GoodsDefaultValue"] = firstGood.Id;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
model.Field(x => x.CGoodCode).DefaultValue(ViewData["GoodsDefaultValue"]);
```

Easy right?!

Comment: Yes, I know that. But it doesn't work for a foreign key, since it shows a dropdown list.

Comment: It doesn't work because you have specify default value which didn't match with all value inside your FK data source. See my updated answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Dion, actually I don't specify the default value inside my controller, because I don't have one! I just want to be able to submit the form without changing value. Currently I get a null. Maybe I should change the code to always select the first item?

Comment: you can't change your controller? you could also do that in razor view.. see my updated answer

Comment: When you have set a default value, it won't be `null` by the first time you edit the data, because it comes to drop down when in edit mode it try to find match value with given default value, yet it couldn't. So the value reset to `null` again. So I suggest you must find the first item `Id` from your controller or you can do that directly in razor view. But I prefer do that inside controller.

Comment: Thanks Dion, you actually answer [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283976/) as well! I changed my controller. Can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345143/) please?